# MySQL crash while mysqldump / mysqlcheck

Tags: mysql, mysqlcheck

everytime I try to backup or check all tables mysql server crashes on Windows server 2012,
I am using XAMPP stack for my development environment.
The database crypto has more then 1100+ tables in DB.
I am including the logs below.

> InnoDB: End of page dump
>   2017-09-24 13:58:35 7dc InnoDB: uncompressed page, stored checksum in field1 2521749199, calculated checksums for field1: crc32 2344073126, innodb 1121903210, none 3735928559, stored checksum in field2 0, calculated checksums for field2: crc32 2344073126, innodb 2892594725, none 3735928559, page LSN 0 2936733816, low 4 bytes of LSN at page end 0, page number (if stored to page already) 34, space id (if created with >= MySQL-4.1.1 and stored already) 1767
>   InnoDB: page type 17855 meaning INDEX
>   InnoDB: Page may be an index page where index id is 1522
>   InnoDB: (index "PRIMARY" of table "crypto"."300-token")
>   2017-09-24 13:58:35 2012 [ERROR] InnoDB: It is also possible that your operatingsystem has corrupted its own file cache.
>   2017-09-24 13:58:35 2012 [ERROR] InnoDB: and rebooting your computer removes the error.
>   2017-09-24 13:58:35 2012 [ERROR] InnoDB: If the corrupt page is an index page you can also try to
>   2017-09-24 13:58:35 2012 [ERROR] InnoDB: fix the corruption by dumping, dropping, and reimporting
>   2017-09-24 13:58:35 2012 [ERROR] InnoDB: the corrupt table. You can use CHECK
>   2017-09-24 13:58:35 2012 [ERROR] InnoDB: TABLE to scan your table for corruption.
>   2017-09-24 13:58:35 2012 [ERROR] InnoDB: See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html about forcing recovery.
>   2017-09-24 13:58:35 7dc  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 2012 in file buf0lru.cc line 2394
>   InnoDB: Failing assertion: bpage->buf_fix_count == 0
>   InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
>   InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
>   InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
>   InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
>   InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
>   InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
>   InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
>   170924 13:58:35 [ERROR] mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;
>   This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
>   or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
>   or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
>
> To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs
>
> We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
>   diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,  something is
>   definitely wrong and this may fail.
>
> Server version: 10.1.22-MariaDB key_buffer_size=16777216
>   read_buffer_size=262144 max_used_connections=1 max_threads=1001
>   thread_count=1 It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
>   key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads =
>   787106 K  bytes of memory Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some
>   variables in the equation.
>
> Thread pointer: 0x0 Attempting backtrace. You can use the following
>   information to find out where mysqld died. If you see no messages
>   after this, something went terribly wrong...
>   mysqld.exe!my_parameter_handler() mysqld.exe!my_wildcmp_mb_bin()
>   mysqld.exe!?save_in_result_field@Item@@UAEX_N@Z()
>   mysqld.exe!?save_in_result_field@Item@@UAEX_N@Z()
>   mysqld.exe!?save_in_result_field@Item@@UAEX_N@Z()
>   mysqld.exe!?save_in_result_field@Item@@UAEX_N@Z()
>   mysqld.exe!?save_in_result_field@Item@@UAEX_N@Z()
>   KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
>   ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain()
>   ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain() The manual page at
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains information
>   that should help you find out what is causing the crash.

I hope someone will help me out
Thanks.

Comment: Try some basic stuff like running ``chkdsk`` and reinstalling MySQL. Windows is generally wonky, so you may want to try this on a Linux system if you can.

Answer (score 0):

From this content in your question,
"Server version: 10.1.22-MariaDB key_buffer_size=16777216 read_buffer_size=262144 max_used_connections=1 max_threads=1001 thread_count=1 It is possible that mysqld could use up to key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 787106 K ...."

with `max_threads=1001` clue above - check for max_connections in your my.ini or .cnf.  Lowering max_connections to = 100 may or may not help get you past the BaseThreadInitThunk() ntdll.dll!